# Как упростить функцию инкремента с проверкой переполнения?

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

```
void char_inc(char& value, const char& inc)
{
    std::cout << "value: " << +value << " inc: " << +inc;

    if (value + inc <= CHAR_MAX)
    {
        std::cout << " ok" << std::endl;
        value += inc;   
    }
    else
        std::cout << " overflow" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    char value = 100; // [-128; 127]

    char_inc(value, 25);    // ok
    char_inc(value, 25);    // overflow

    system("pause");
}
```

Можно ли упростить функцию инкремента?

Comment: Возможно, что скажу глупость, но я бы использовал try() catch{} для ловли переполнения для стандартных типов. Нужен эксперимент.

Comment: Если это реальный проект, то тогда имеет смысл не изобретать велосипед и использовать готовые бибилиотеки, такие как [boost Safe Numerics](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/safe_numerics/doc/html/index.html) или [Safe int](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/safeint-library?view=vs-2017). @АлександрМуксимов Переполнение для встроенных беззнаковых типов является неопределенным поведением.

Comment: @VTT, это встраиваемый код, который будет крутиться на слабеньком проце, буст и мс туда затащить нельзя, поэтому велосипеды, спасибо за наводку, посмотрюб реализацию в бусте

Comment: *будет крутиться на слабеньком проце* - *буст и мс туда затащить нельзя* - не видно связи

Comment: @VTT, да я могу ошибиться, давно не писал на С - Ваше предложение по поводу boost лучше.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, функция не должна ничего выводить на консоль. Это решение пользователя функции, выводить что-либо на консоль по результату вызова функции или нет.

Поэтому более логически разумно выглядит, когда функция возвращает значение типа `bool`, говорящее о том, была ли успешной операция инкремента или нет.

Кроме того, если тип `char` ведет себя как тип `signed char`, то может быть переполнение не только "сверху", но и "снизу".

Кроме того, нет никакого смысла второй параметр объявлять как ссылку. Сам тип char является встроенным типом, и для создании его копии не требуется каких-либо излишних ресурсов.

Я бы объявил функцию следующим образом, как показано в демонстрационной программе.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

bool char_inc( char &value, char inc )
{
    int sum = value + inc;

    return sum <= std::numeric_limits<char>::max() && 
           std::numeric_limits<char>::min() <= sum
           ? ( value = sum, true )
           : false;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "acceptable range is [ " 
              << static_cast<int>( std::numeric_limits<char>::min() )
              << ", " 
              << static_cast<int>( std::numeric_limits<char>::max() ) 
              << " ]\n";

    char c = 'A';

    if ( char_inc( c, ' ' ) )
    {
        std::cout << "The new value of 'c' is " << c << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
acceptable range is [ -128, 127 ]
The new value of 'c' is a
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
std::string s = (value <= CHAR_MAX - inc)
        ? "ok" : " overflow";
std::cout << "value: " << +value << " inc: " << +inc
          << s << std::endl;
if (s == "ok")  value += inc;
```

Но, в принципе, пользователь  `Vlad from Moscow` прав:  более логически разумно выглядит, когда функция возвращает значение типа bool, говорящее о том, была ли успешной операция инкремента или нет...

Comment: Спасибо, `value <= CHAR_MAX - inc` - вот это мне нравится больше, чем через инт

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. А мне больше нравится ответ от  Vlad from Moscow.